# Access components of JFrame within MouseAdapter

Tags: java, adapter

what is the right way to access elements from a parent component when an adapter is used? Example:

In my JFrame is a Menu with an item "Connect". I handle the "pressed" event with a MouseAdapter:

```
mntmConnect.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            mainDialog.getY();
        }
    });
```

As you can see I want to access components or methods of the mainDialog where this Menu(item) belongs to. But in that MouseAdapter of course no "mainDialog" is known.

So here are my approaches:

**1. Declare attributes that a needed as final**

**2. Create your own MouseAdapter that takes "mainDialog" as a variable in the ctor**

Both of them seem circumstantial to me. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the right way to do this?

All 3 of these approaches are right.

1. Declare attributes that are needed for an anonymous class as final.
2. Declare attributes that are needed for an anonymous class as class global.
3. Create a `MouseAdapter` class that takes "mainDialog" as a variable in the constructor.

I tend to use 2 for small `MouseAdapter` anonymous classes.

I tend to use 3 for larger `MouseAdapter` classes.  I make these separate classes and put them in a controller package.

Answer (score 0):

> I handle the "pressed" event with a MouseAdapter

You should NOT be doing this. You should be adding and ActionListener (or Action) to the JMenuItem.

All compnents have a parent. So if you want to know the parent window of the menu item that was clicked you need to keep finding the parents component until you reach the window. Here is one way:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MenuItemFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public MenuItemFrame()
    {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar( menuBar );

        JMenu menu = new JMenu( "File" );
        menuBar.add( menu );

        JMenuItem item1 = new JMenuItem("Item 1");
        item1.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F2, 0, false));

        menu.add( item1 );

        JMenu subMenu1 = new JMenu("SubMenu 1");
        menu.add( subMenu1 );

        JMenuItem subItem1 = new JMenuItem("SubItem 1");
        subMenu1.add( subItem1 );

        JMenu subMenu12 = new JMenu("SubMenu 12");
        subMenu1.add( subMenu12 );

        JMenuItem subItem12 = new JMenuItem("SubItem 12");
        subMenu12.add( subItem12 );

        item1.addActionListener( this );
        subItem1.addActionListener( this );
        subItem12.addActionListener( this );
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        JMenuItem mi = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
        mi.setText(mi.getText() + "0");
        JMenu menu = getMenuBarMenu(mi);

        JRootPane rootPane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(menu);
        JFrame frame = (JFrame)SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(menu);
        System.out.println(frame);

    }

    public JMenu getMenuBarMenu(JMenuItem item)
    {
        JMenu menu = null;

        while (menu == null)
        {
            JPopupMenu popup = (JPopupMenu)item.getParent();
            item = (JMenuItem)popup.getInvoker();

            if (! (item.getParent() instanceof JPopupMenu) )
                menu = (JMenu)item;
        }

        return menu;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new MenuItemFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```